# right click not working ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I see this question asked several times and it appears to me all of the answers suggest a "work around".  They suggest a way of changing from a two finger click on the mouse pad to a single click on the mouse pad.  I don't see any responses that show a way to get the actual right mouse button to work.  Or am I just not looking in the right spot?

Comment: So what's your right button doing? Is it selecting things like what we expect from left button?

Comment: Yes it is acting like the left button

Comment: Go to `Settings->Devices->Mouse and Touchpad` and change `Primary Button` to `Left`. let me know if it helps.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference

Comment: Feels more like 1998 than 2018, the fact that this functionality doesn't exist.

Comment: My right click has magically started working, some update I assume?  Anyone else have the same thing happen?

Comment: I did what @Kulfy told, although my mouse was already selected to be primarily the Left button. So, I switched to Right then back to Left. And out of the blue the right click started to work again.